# Django-Project folder not found inside a script

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem including the settings.py file inside a script. My django project uses a script that fills my database with models. To do this, I use following code:

```
  # some imports 
        
 import <project_name>.settings as app_settings

 from <app_name>.models import ( .... different models)

 settings.configure(
  INSTALLED_APPS=app_settings.INSTALLED_APPS,
  DATABASES=app_setttings.DATABASES
 )

 django.setup()

 # read file external file and insert data (model) into the db.sqlite3 database
```

The problem is that the module <project_name> can not be found. The above script is in the project directory.

The error is thrown in line `import <project_name>.settings as app_settings`. :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<project_name>'`

Why can't the script include the project folder?

Comment: In this case, you just need `import settings as app_settings`

if you include <project_name> it assumes that is an app name and fails to find it.  Is that what you're after or do you want a deeper explanation about why project names aren't part of the namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
import settings as app_settings
```

You don't need to specify project's name, if you're working within this project's area. Hope that will work for you!